# is "are you listening to yourself" similar to "are you honest to yourself"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Some websites say "**are you listening to yourself?**" = "**Are you understanding what you're saying?**" [Source](https://www.italki.com/question/92113)

I don't think the above explains accurately.

I think "**are you listening to yourself?**" is similar to "**are you honest to yourself**"?

[This site](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=Y8QFh1qle-cC&pg=PT82&lpg=PT82&dq=%22listening%20to%20yourself%22%20definition&source=bl&ots=MWpKJXwbgg&sig=VfUXpBT5GbZVNskiUUQMFpGV_uQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8rautx7vOAhUDSSYKHb3hDAY4ChDoAQggMAE#v=onepage&q&f=false) said "*Listening to yourself means noticing the voice in your head and your intuition or gut feeling. When you are in a situation, be aware of the wisdom that your body, mind, and spirit are offering you.*"

So, is "**are you listening to yourself**" similar to "**are you honest to yourself**" or "**listening to what your soul are providing for you**"?

Comment: I think "Are you listening to yourself?" is more like saying "Are you crazy?" or "Are you out of your mind?".

Comment: A native speaker would _never_ say _"Are you honest to yourself?"_ We would say: _"Are you honest with yourself?"_

Comment: @Tom Note that the italki page has nothing about *listening*. It's about *listen*. This may or may not make a real difference in different contexts, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**listen to yourself**, on its own, is self-help terminology with a variety of different meanings depending on which self-help guru is speaking or writing- be honest with yourself, listen to your soul, believe in yourself, trust your gut feeling, etc. If a self-help guru says **are you listening to yourself?**, you have to take it in the context of what they have written to understand what it means.

When an ordinary person says **are you listening to yourself?**, it means

> You are talking rubbish, and if you stopped and thought about what you were saying, you would realise that.

Here is an example from [the West Wing](http://communicationsoffice.tripod.com/1-13.txt), in which C.J. uses this expression to Mandy: listen to it, and I think you will agree that C.J. is **not** trying to offer Mandy self-help advice.

Comment: Maybe "are you listening to yourself" has 2 meanings. 1-"meaning you are talking rubbish" used in everyday conversation like you said. 2-"meaning listening to your soul or something like that" in philosophy http://www.beliefnet.com/columnists/awakenyourtruth/2015/07/are-you-listening-to-yourself.html

Comment: also see http://clarisconsulting.net/are-you-listening-to-yourself/

Comment: Here it said "listening to yourself means you believe in yourself and make decisions that are the best for yourself. Only you know you the best. Noone knows you better than you do" http://balanceinme.com/blog/listen-to-yourself/

Comment: Here it said "Listening to yourself means noticing the voice in your head and your intuition or gut feeling. When you are in a situation, be aware of the wisdom that your body, mind, and spirit are offering you." https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=Y8QFh1qle-cC&pg=PT82&lpg=PT82&dq=%22listening+to+yourself%22+definition&source=bl&ots=MWpKJXwbgg&sig=VfUXpBT5GbZVNskiUUQMFpGV_uQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8rautx7vOAhUDSSYKHb3hDAY4ChDoAQggMAE#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Tom, you should really update your question to include these references so that I, and other answerers, can address them  in our answers, rather than in a comment.